# How can update file content based on grunt-init prompt answers?

Tags: angularjs, grunt-init

I have created a custom angularjs project using grunt-init. And want to edit the app module name based on answers given to the prompt while creating the project.  But somehow I keep on getting blank string when I use the props object.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I was not using the props template correctly. The right way to use it is as below,

var moduleName = "{%= name %}"